# Lotus Notes version 5.0.8 database migration

Tags: lotus-notes

This is my first time ever working with Lotus Notes, where the client want to move its database  to mysql.

I have spent a week to read on Lotus Notes but going nowhere. When I search for some tool to migrate database, it does not support version 5.

It is a better idea to upgrade to latest version and than migrate...please advice...

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can update to latest IBM Notes/Domino version and database will still run without any change. That is one of the cool things about Notes...

Comment: Hi, thanks...is there a way to find out number of tables and list of all field names.

Comment: As IBM Notes is a document oriented system there are no data tables like in relational database systems. A good way to find out about application's data structure is to look at the forms and views. In forms are defined (almost) all the fields. In views are listed documents created by forms. Other ways are using Notes-ODBC or to export/transform database design as XML (=DXL) at menue "Tools / DXL Utilities" in Notes Designer.